# How can I make the C# .net POCO thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, .net-core

I am new in C# .net and I'm currently working on a Selenium C# Project that have the BrowserFactory class and have POCO named Driver.

And the InitBrowser method sets its value.

When trying to run the test using Parallel Test in NUnitFramework having 2 parallel tests, it will certainly have an error because as you can see the code is not thread safe so it will not be able to work on parallel test environments.

Below is the code:

```
namespace SeleniumAutomationFramework.WrapperFactory {
    class BrowserFactory
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<string, IWebDriver> Drivers = new Dictionary<string, IWebDriver>();
        private static IWebDriver driver;


        public static IWebDriver Driver
        {
            get
            {
                if (driver == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. Try to call the method InitBrowser instead.");
                return driver;
            }
            private set
            {
                driver = value;
            }
        }

        public static void InitBrowser(string browserName)
        {
            switch(browserName.ToLower())
            {
                case "firefox":
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    Drivers.Add("Firefox", Driver);
                    break;

                case "chrome":
                    var options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.AddArguments(
                        "--headless",
                        "--no-sandbox",
                        "--disable-dev-shm-usage"
                            );

                    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                    Drivers.Add("Chrome", Driver);
                    break;

                case "ie":
                        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                        Drivers.Add("IE", Driver);
                    break;

                //case "chromium":
                //        driver = new ChromeDriver();
                //    break;

                default:
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    Drivers.Add("Chrome", Driver);
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static void LoadApplication(string url)
        {
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }

        public static void CloseAllDrivers()
        {
            foreach (var key in Drivers.Keys)
            {
                Drivers[key].Close();
                Drivers[key].Quit();
            }
        }
    } }
```

**The Driver property is being called by a Page Generator class.**

```
namespace SeleniumAutomationFramework.PageObjects
{
    public static class Page
    {
        private static T GetPage<T>() where T : new()
        {
            var page = new T();
            PageFactory.InitElements(BrowserFactory.Driver, page);
            return page;
        }

        public static HomePage Home
        {
            get { return GetPage<HomePage>();  }
        }

        public static LoginPage Login
        {
            get { return GetPage<LoginPage>(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a POCO here by the way, a POCO is just a simple class (Plain Old CLR Object)

Comment: Oh I meant a DTO?

Comment: Well it's also not a DTO, that is usually a class with only properties and no business logic in at all :)

Comment: Okay, so what is this '''public static IWebDriver Driver''' called?

Comment: That's just a static property.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use Lazy class and ConcurrentDictionary.

But what's the reason to have Driver property? If it runs parallel, you have only the last loaded driver. So for all test you will use one Driver. I think you should use ConcurrentDictionary only and do it like this

**Update to better fit the reqierements**

**Code I would use**

```
class BrowserFactory
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IWebDriver> Drivers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IWebDriver>();

    private static IWebDriver InitDriver(string browserName)
    {
        switch (browserName.ToLower())
        {
            case "firefox":
                return new FirefoxDriver();
            case "chrome":
                var options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArguments(
                    "--headless",
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "--disable-dev-shm-usage"
                );

                return new ChromeDriver(options);
            case "ie":
                return InternetExplorerDriver();

            default:
                return new ChromeDriver();
        }
    }

    public static IWebDriver GetDriver(string browserName)
    {
        if (!Drivers.ContainsKey(browserName))
        {
            var driver = InitDriver(browserName);
            Drivers.TryAdd(browserName, driver);
        }
        return Drivers[browserName];
    }

    public static void LoadApplication(string browserName, string url)
    {
        Drivers[browserName].Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    }

    // close should be called explicit by browserName or driver directly
    // by closing all drivers you will broke all other still running tests
    /*
    public static void CloseAllDrivers()
    {
        foreach (var key in Drivers.Keys)
        {
            Drivers[key].Close();
            Drivers[key].Quit();
        }
    }
    */
}

public abstract class PageBase
{
    protected PageBase(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        Driver = driver;
    }

    protected IWebDriver Driver { get; private set; }
}

public class HomePage : PageBase
{
    public HomePage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
    }

    public IWebElement SomeElement => Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("selector"));
}
```

Then create the page just like this

```
var page = new HomePage(BrowserFactory.GetDriver("chrome"));
```

Comment: I've updated the body of the question. The thing is the Driver property is being called by the Page Generator class where it needs the value of the Driver.

Comment: So when I'm trying to run in parallel. I am having the below error.

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
      ----> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)

Comment: You can add public static IWebDriver GetDriver(string browserName) method and return the driver from dictionary

Comment: I see, I'm preventing to do multiple passing of browsername, that's why I've created the Drivers static property.

Comment: Static driver property does not help in parallel envionment. Either you have to pass browsername and use the GetDriver method, or you change your tests so, that the BrowseFactory returns an instance of the driver on the InitBrowser method and you can use this reference in you browser specific test case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213856/discussion-between-demetrius-axenowski-and-harvey).

Comment: @Harvey was it helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution would be to stop using [global fields](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) (i.e. static properties/methods) and instead create a object that is handed to all components that need this functionality. You probably also want to make an interface for this object. This would allow your unit tests to use a mock object instead of the real thing. This would avoid a bunch of web-browsers popping up when you run your unit tests.

The worse solution would be to just add lock statements to all public methods,

```
static object lockObj = new object();
public static MyPublicMethod(){
    lock(lockObj){
         // Logic
    }
}
```